# Avoid temporary page when using tikzexternalize

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is the output of `tikzexternalize`
[image]

This will appear for most figures in document. Sure I can manually/automatically delete these pages, however I wonder what can be wrong and how to avoid it. There are figures in the document which are generated properly as standalone as expected which confuses me.

Can you suggest what is the common problem because I can't see the difference between the ones that come out bad and the ones that come out good.

I cannot provide full document/MWE as it is still under review.

Comment: It's understandable that you cannot share your actual document, but maybe you can make a test version with a very simple graphic that reproduces this behavior? Without any code it is very difficult to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: you need to provide an example (it is always possible to make an MWE avoiding private data) something in the example is causing some unprocessed items to appear on a following page, but impossible to debug with no code